# Uniform convergence of functions and limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $f_{n}, f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function on a compact metric space $X$. Assume that $\frac{1}{n}f_{n}(x) \to f(x).$ Then, $f_{n}(x)-na \to f(x)-a$,right? If so, one can also say that $\frac{1}{n}(f_{n}(x)-na) \to f(x)-a.$ But, I can take a factor $n$, and then $\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{n}f_{n}(x)-a)$ which does not converge to $f(x)-a$.

I am pretty sure that I am missing something, but I don’t know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_n(x)=\sqrt n, f(x)=0, a=0$ for all $x$ then $\frac {f_n(x)} n \to f(x)$ but $f_n(x)-na\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

> Then, $f_{n}(x)-na \to f(x)-a$, right?

Why? $\frac{f_n(x)-a}{n}\to f(x)-a$ holds, not $f_n(x)-a\to f(x)-a$!